# Rails relationship confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, models

I am trying to get some relationships in Rails set up and am having some confusion with how to use the ones I have configured.

My scenario is this:
I have a model called `Coaster`. I wish each Coaster to be able to have 0 or more versions. I wish to be able to find all versions of a Coaster from it's instance and also in reverse.

My models and relationships as they stand:

coaster.rb:

```
has_many :incarnations
has_many :coaster_versions,
  through: :incarnations
```

incarnation.rb:

```
belongs_to :coaster
belongs_to :coaster_version,
           class_name: "Coaster",
           foreign_key: "coaster_id"
```

Database schema for Incarnations:

```
create_table "incarnations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "coaster_id"
  t.integer "is_version_of_id"
  t.boolean "is_latest"
  t.integer "version_order"
end
```

and my code that happens when importing Coasters from my CSV data file:

```
 # Versions
 # Now determine if this is a new version of existing coaster or not
 if Coaster.where(order_ridden: row[:order_ridden]).count == 1

   # Create Coaster Version that equals itself.
   coaster.incarnations.create!({is_version_of_id: coaster.id, is_latest: true})
 else

   # Set original and/or previous incarnations of this coaster to not be latest
   Coaster.where(order_ridden: row[:order_ridden]).each do |c|
     c.incarnations.each do |i|
       i.update({is_latest: false})
     end
   end

   # Add new incarnation by finding original version
   original_coaster = Coaster.unscoped.where(order_ridden: row[:order_ridden]).order(version_number: :asc).first
   coaster.incarnations.create!({is_version_of_id: original_coaster.id, is_latest: true})
```

Now all my DB tables get filled in but I am unsure how to ensure everything is working how I want it to.

For example I have two coasters (A and B), B is a version of A. When I get A and ask for a count of it's `coaster_versions`, I only get 1 returned as a result?  Surely I should get 2 or is that correct?

In the same line, if I get B and call `coaster_versions` I get 1 returned as well.

I just need to ensure I am getting back the correct results really.

Any comments would be highly appreciated as I have been working on this for ages now and not getting very far.

Just incase anyone is going to reply telling me to look at versioning gems. I went this route initially and it was great but the problem there is that in MY case a Coaster and a VERSION of a coaster are both as important as each other and I can't do Coaster.all to get ALL coasters whether they were versions or not. Other issues along the same line also cropped up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to the wonderful world of history tracking! As you've found, it's not actually that easy to keep track of how your data changes in a relational database. And while there are definitely gems out there that can just track history for audit purposes (e.g. `auditable`), sounds like you want your history records to still be first-class citizens. So, let me first analyze the problems with your current approach, and then I'll propose a simpler solution that might make your life easier.

In no particular order, here are some pain points with your current system:

1. The `is_latest` column has to be maintained, and is at risk for going out of sync. You likely wouldn't see this in testing, but in production, at scale, it's a very valid risk.
2. Your `incarnations` table creates a one-master-version-with-many-child-versions structure, which is fine except that (similar to is_latest) the ordering of the versions is controlled by the `version_order` column which again needs to be maintained and is at risk of being incorrect. Your import script doesn't seem to set it, at the moment.
3. The `incarnations` relationship makes it difficult to tell that B is a version of A; you could fix this with some more relations, but that will also make your code more complex.
4. Complexity. It's hard to follow how history is tracked, and as you've found, it's hard to manage the details of inserting a new version (A and B should both agree that they have 2 versions, right? Since they're the same coaster?)

Now, I think your data model is still technically valid -- the issues you're seeing are, I think, problems with your script. However, with a simpler data model, your script could become much simpler and thus less prone to error. Here's how I'd do it, using just one table:

```
create_table "coasters", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "original_version_id"
  t.datetime "superseded_at"
  t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
end
```

The `original_version_id` serves the same purpose as your `incarnations` table does, to link a version back to the original record. The `superseded_at` column is both usable as an `is_latest` check and a way to order the versions (though below, I just order by `id` for simplicity). With that structure, this is my Coaster class:

```
class Coaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :original_version, class_name: "Coaster"

  scope :latest,   -> { where(superseded_at: nil) }
  scope :original, -> { where('original_version_id = id') }

  # Create a new record, linked properly in history.
  def self.insert(attrs)
    # Find the current latest version.
    if previous_coaster = Coaster.latest.find_by(name: attrs[:name])
      # At the same time, create the new version (linked back to the original version)
      # and deprecate the current latest version. A transaction ensures either both
      # happen, or neither do.
      transaction do
        create!(attrs.merge(original_version_id: previous_coaster.original_version_id))
        previous_coaster.update_column(:superseded_at, Time.now)
      end
    else
      # Create the first version. Set its original version id to itself, to simplify
      # our logic.
      transaction do
        new_record = create!(attrs)
        new_record.update_column(:original_version_id, new_record.id)
      end
    end
  end

  # Retrieve all records linked to the same original version. This will return the
  # same result for any of the versions.
  def versions
    self.class.where(original_version_id: original_version_id)
  end

  # Return our version as an ordinal, e.g. 1 for the very first version.
  def version
    versions.where(['id <= ?', id]).count
  end
end
```

This makes adding new records simple:

```
irb> 5.times { Coaster.insert(name: "Coaster A") }
irb> 4.times { Coaster.insert(name: "Coaster B") }
irb> Coaster.latest.find_by(name: "Coaster A").version
   (2.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "coasters" WHERE "coasters"."original_version_id" = $1 AND (id <= 11)  [["original_version_id", 7]]
=> 5
irb> Coaster.original.find_by(name: "Coaster A").version
   (2.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "coasters" WHERE "coasters"."original_version_id" = $1 AND (id <= 7)  [["original_version_id", 7]]
=> 1
```

Granted, it's still complex code that would be nice to have made simpler. My approach is certainly not the only one, nor necessarily the best. Hopefully you learned something, though!

Comment: Thankyou so much. Going to have to read through that several times. Just some more info about my scenario here:

1. For now at least, ALL Coasters are added to the DB at once when I run an import script and everything is pulled in from an external CSV which I update manually.

2. A version in this scenario is defined as a coaster I have ridden before but is now in a different location, under a different name or has had heavy modifications to it.

I will read through your post several times and make amendments to my project over the next week and report back.

Comment: Thankyou once again for your help. I implemented it all yesterday with a few alterations to fit my needs and it works perfectly. So great to see a fresh take on the problem and how my idea could be simplified. I have taken a lot from your answer. Please could you explain how this line works: `scope :original, -> { where('original_version_id = id') }`?

Comment: Sure. It's a [rails scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope), which provides a quick way to query only records returned by the value of the lambda (the `-> { }` syntax is a fancy way to pass in a block). The `where` clause itself just selects records where their ID is also the original version's ID, i.e., the "original" versions.